# Detect metaphor based on co-occurrence of words in different columns

Tags: python-3.x

I want a code that can detect metaphors based on the co-occurrence of words from the two columns (source domain and target domain). For example; if I enter the sentence (she broke his heart) the model is supposed to detect the metaphor because the two words (broke) and (heart) appear in the columns (source domain and target domain). In other words, I need a model that can learn all the words in the two columns (source domain and target domain) and be able to detect a metaphor in any input text that includes any two (or more) words that exist in these two columns. [I have included an image of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLbpx.png)

Comment: You haven't asked a question yet.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So we have two columns in the table: the source domain and the target domain. Each column contains words that are part of metaphors. I want a model that can detect metaphors by searching the existence of the words in the two columns in order to determine if the input phrase/sentence is metaphorical or not.   
But how? I give the model a phrase/sentence. The model searches the sentence, if it can find one word or more in the sentence that already exists in the two columns, then this sentence is metaphorical; otherwise, it is not.